# New sign-ups to Congito User pool default to disabled

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito User pools and the hosted Cognito UI. I want new users to be disabled when they first sign-up.

I am trying to use a Cognito Trigger to disable the user.
The "Pre sign-up" trigger is to soon, the user has not been created yet. I have successfully used the "Post confirmation" to disable the user, however this is causing a side effect. After the user enters the confirmation code which is emailed to them, they see this message in the hosted UI "User is disabled".

Does anyone have a suggested solution on how to make the new users disabled by default?

Comment: Do you have to use the disabled feature on cognito to disable your users? Can you just add a UserDisabled to their user profile to hide certain functionality? I'm not sure if it makes sense to have a user create an account they can't delete or edit at all.

Comment: The idea is that when someone signs up, the custom congito trigger will also email the sales team, if they recognise the sign up as someone who should have access, they will immediately re-activate the account (The product is still MVP). Thanks for the suggestion, we are looking at alternative options.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar Business Requirement. For us we made use of a User Pool Group. This allowed the sign up and validation process to work as normal. We had the Post Confirmation trigger send our product team an email with details about the new confirmed user. We had a simple UI for the product team to add the group to a user if they should have access.

To Deny/Grant Access to the app: Our app checked the ID Token, once a user successfully authenticated, for the group (the ID Token has a 'cognito:groups' key which contains a list of all the groups the user is in). If the group was not present we displayed a page showing the user a customized *access denied* message

Comment: Thank you for sharing your use case! It's beneficial for designing the flow from the business perspective.